# Net stops working everyday at the same time

Tags: networking

I have weird behavior on my Ubuntu 19.04. Everyday at approximately the same time my network stops working. When I ping my router I get

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

I also can't connect to services running on localhost e.g. mongo. Restart helps, but I dont even know from where to start to fix this problem.

Comment: Look for cron jobs and / or malware in your computer... Does any other computer or device on your network has a similar problem? Did you try booting your computer with Live CD?

Comment: Didnt find any suspicious cron jobs, and malware scan found nothing. other devices on the network have no issues